# tf message published by rgbdslam

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The /tf message published by rgbdslam package is before g2o optimization or after g2o optimization?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67034/tf-message-published-by-rgbdslam/) by [wwl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5374/wwl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-10-13**:
@felix endres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After optimization.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1